# My c++ software is a collection of too many exe's, how do I manage it

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, exe, shared

I wrote a c++ program to do a variety of things. I realized that some of the software should be targeted for x86 (because it uses a 3rd party library that can only be compiled on x86), and then the rest of the software should be targeted for x64, and the two exe's communicate through shared memory. I then added a 3rd exe to communicate with the network and save stuff to the hard-drive and deal with network outages.

Long story short, I have three exe's; really working together to doing one task.

How can I manage all this into a user friendly program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the user only has to launch one of them, which then launches the others invisibly, there's nothing wrong with this at all, and in fact it's rather common.

Comment: Right now, the user does have to launch them. How can I have them launch automatically?

Comment: Depends on the platform, but just use CreateProcess() on Windows, or fork/exec on UNIX.

Comment: @rossb83: Or you can use a batch file on Windows and a bash script on Unix.